# How do I mute the audio coming from a UIWebView

Tags: ios, audio, uiwebview

My app includes a UIWebView with 3rd party content.  The content sometimes includes html5 videos.  I'd like a way to mute the html5 audio when a user mutes the audio through my app's settings or via the ring/silent switch.

I've tried using all of these to no avail:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil]];
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m wondering the same thing. I have a UIWebView that plays HTML5 audio. I’m thinking a solution will be two parts:

I have to explicitly allow audio playback in the webview:

```
// Allow audio playback in the UIWebView:
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

So, if there’s a way to conditionally set those to their opposites when the silent switch is off, that’ll do it.

Problem is, it doesn’t appear there’s a way to do this in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: I'm almost certain that it isn't possible

Comment: Actually, found a developer who’s selling an archive that claims to do just this: http://www.verietassoftware.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27&Itemid=115 (I tried their sample app, and it works on my 4S running iOS 5.1.)

Comment: That is an interesting library but it just tells you if the ring silent switch is enabled.  It doesn't provide any means of silencing the audio emanating from a UIWebView.